# aws cli: invalid security token on my local windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, access-keys

**I try to connect by aws cli from my laptop which has windows. I create access key and secret key by IAM on root use several times and use aws configure to set them, but I still get invalid token error. I know that my credential is set because when I run aws configure it shows up. The below is the log. Thanks for help.**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************PAPA]:
AWS Secret Access Key [****************vXOi]:
Default region name [us-east-1]:
Default output format [json]:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> aws lambda list-functions --debug
2019-01-27 15:14:36,022 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.16.96 Python/3.7.2 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.86
2019-01-27 15:14:36,023 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Arguments entered to CLI: ['lambda', 'list-functions', '--debug']
2019-01-27 15:14:36,023 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x000001A242791488>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,023 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function register_uri_param_handler at 0x000001A242288620>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,023 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider_cache at 0x000001A2422C47B8>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,025 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function attach_history_handler at 0x000001A2425087B8>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,026 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\lambda\2015-03-31\service-2.json
2019-01-27 15:14:36,029 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.lambda: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x000001A241FBED08>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,029 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: lambda
2019-01-27 15:14:36,030 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.lambda: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x000001A24279B950>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,065 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([('master-region', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921B00>), ('function-version', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921B38>), ('marker', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921C50>), ('max-items', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921BA8>)])
2019-01-27 15:14:36,065 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x000001A242791730>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,065 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x000001A2422C4EA0>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,066 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x000001A24271B9D8>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,103 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\lambda\2015-03-31\paginators-1.json
2019-01-27 15:14:36,104 - MainThread - awscli.customizations.paginate - DEBUG - Modifying paging parameters for operation: ListFunctions
2019-01-27 15:14:36,104 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x000001A2426F78C8>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,105 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <bound method OverrideRequiredArgsArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x000001A242921CF8>>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,105 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x000001A242930208>>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,105 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event operation-args-parsed.lambda.list-functions: calling handler functools.partial(<function check_should_enable_pagination at 0x000001A24271BAE8>, ['marker', 'max-items'], {'max-items': <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921BA8>}, OrderedDict([('master-region', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921B00>), ('function-version', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921B38>), ('marker', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x000001A242921C50>), ('max-items', <awscli.customizations.paginate.PageArgument object at 0x000001A242930128>), ('cli-input-json', <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x000001A242921CF8>), ('starting-token', <awscli.customizations.paginate.PageArgument object at 0x000001A242921D68>), ('page-size', <awscli.customizations.paginate.PageArgument object at 0x000001A242930080>), ('generate-cli-skeleton', <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x000001A242930208>)]))
2019-01-27 15:14:36,106 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.master-region: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,106 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.function-version: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,106 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.marker: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,107 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.max-items: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,107 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.cli-input-json: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,107 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.starting-token: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,108 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.page-size: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,108 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.lambda.list-functions.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at 0x000001A24286CF60>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,108 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x000001A242921CF8>>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,108 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.lambda.list-functions: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_json_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x000001A242930208>>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,109 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2019-01-27 15:14:36,109 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.
2019-01-27 15:14:36,110 - MainThread - botocore.loaders - DEBUG - Loading JSON file: C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\data\endpoints.json
2019-01-27 15:14:36,112 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-service-name: calling handler <function handle_service_name_alias at 0x000001A241F990D0>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,113 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event creating-client-class.lambda: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x000001A241F58F28>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,117 - MainThread - botocore.args - DEBUG - The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2019-01-27 15:14:36,119 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Setting lambda timeout as (60, 60)
2019-01-27 15:14:36,120 - MainThread - botocore.client - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: lambda
2019-01-27 15:14:36,121 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-parameter-build.lambda.ListFunctions: calling handler <function generate_idempotent_uuid at 0x000001A241FBE6A8>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,121 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-call.lambda.ListFunctions: calling handler <function inject_api_version_header_if_needed at 0x000001A241FC1598>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,121 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for OperationModel(name=ListFunctions) with params: {'url_path': '/2015-03-31/functions/', 'query_string': {}, 'method': 'GET', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'aws-cli/1.16.96 Python/3.7.2 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.86'}, 'body': b'', 'url': 'https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/', 'context': {'client_region': 'us-east-1', 'client_config': <botocore.config.Config object at 0x000001A242A2BAC8>, 'has_streaming_input': False, 'auth_type': None}}
2019-01-27 15:14:36,122 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event request-created.lambda.ListFunctions: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x000001A242A2BA90>>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,122 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event choose-signer.lambda.ListFunctions: calling handler <function set_operation_specific_signer at 0x000001A241FBE598>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,123 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2019-01-27 15:14:36,123 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
GET
/2015-03-31/functions/

host:lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20190127T211436Z

host;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
2019-01-27 15:14:36,123 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20190127T211436Z
20190127/us-east-1/lambda/aws4_request
ce9b2c421afea074503fa22c16a82ef192791150d3fd511cc69409b18f20f300
2019-01-27 15:14:36,123 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
8d4a2a782be3622cc0ecac9e69eabb786feb7126f38851c10314155944fe359a
2019-01-27 15:14:36,124 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <AWSPreparedRequest stream_output=False, method=GET, url=https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/, headers={'User-Agent': b'aws-cli/1.16.96 Python/3.7.2 Windows/10 botocore/1.12.86', 'X-Amz-Date': b'20190127T211436Z', 'Authorization': b'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIAC5Q6NZD6TIRSKQ/20190127/us-east-1/lambda/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=8d4a2a782be3622cc0ecac9e69eabb786feb7126f38851c10314155944fe359a'}>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,124 - MainThread - urllib3.util.retry - DEBUG - Converted retries value: False -> Retry(total=False, connect=None, read=None, redirect=0, status=None)
2019-01-27 15:14:36,124 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
2019-01-27 15:14:36,445 - MainThread - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - https://lambda.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 "GET /2015-03-31/functions/ HTTP/1.1" 403 68
2019-01-27 15:14:36,446 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response headers: {'Date': 'Sun, 27 Jan 2019 21:14:37 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '68', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-RequestId': '8d5f8d34-2278-11e9-b7ef-bd100b83dc62', 'x-amzn-ErrorType': 'UnrecognizedClientException'}
2019-01-27 15:14:36,447 - MainThread - botocore.parsers - DEBUG - Response body:
b'{"message":"The security token included in the request is invalid."}'
2019-01-27 15:14:36,448 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.lambda.ListFunctions: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x000001A242911630>
2019-01-27 15:14:36,448 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - No retry needed.
2019-01-27 15:14:36,450 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 207, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 348, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 520, in __call__
    call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 641, in invoke
    self._display_response(operation_name, response, parsed_globals)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\awscli\clidriver.py", line 661, in _display_response
    formatter(command_name, response)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\awscli\formatter.py", line 69, in __call__
    response_data = response.build_full_result()
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 449, in build_full_result
    for response in self:
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 255, in __iter__
    response = self._make_request(current_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\paginate.py", line 332, in _make_request
    return self._method(**current_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\navid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 661, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
2019-01-27 15:14:36,451 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the ListFunctions operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you can [provide credentials to the awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html), and they are evaluated in the following order:

1. command line options
2. environment variables
3. awscli credentials file
4. awscli config file
5. container credentials
6. instance profile credentials

By running `aws configure` you have configured a set of credentials for option #3.

However, in the debug output that you shared with us, you can see:

> INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.

This suggests that the awscli found credentials in your environment (via environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and possibly `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`). This is option #2 above, which trumps option #3. This also explains why the error you are seeing is "The *security token* included in the request is invalid."

So, your configured credentials are being overridden by environment credentials. Remove the credentials from your environment, and then re-run the awscli.

Comment: @navid Hi, if this solves the problem then please accept as the answer so others know it’s answered.